# on() doesn't work with live data using jQuery, how to?

Tags: jquery-mobile, onclick, jquery, jquery-on

i have some dynamic data that gets appended to a list and any links in that data doesnt seem to work.

i am using jquery 1.8.3 and `on()` should account for the `live` method, i think

```
setInterval(function () {
    getNot();
}, 2000);

function getNot() {
    var data = {
        t1: 'test1',
        t2: 'test2',
        t3: 'test3'
    };
    var size = 0,
        li = '';
    $.each(data, function (k, v) {
        li += '<li>' +
            '<a href="#" class="add" data-listid="' + k + '">' +
            '<h2>load data - ' + k + '</h2>' +
            '</a>' +
            '</li>';
        size++;
    });

    var but = $('#not'),
        ul = $('#not_ul');

    but.find('span').text(size + ' Notifications');
    ul.html(li);
    ul.listview().listview("refresh");
}

// this doesn't seem to work
$('.add').on("click", function () {
    var listId = $(this).data('listid');
    console.log(listId);
    return false;
});
```

[see full example here](http://jsbin.com/ilumov/39/edit)

any ideas on this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.add').on("click", function () {
```

You need to pass a selector to make `on` generate a *delegate event*:

```
$('#{containerId}').on("click", '.add', function () {
    var listId = $(this).data('listid');
    console.log(listId);
    return false;
});
```

`containerId` should be the closest **static** element to the dynamic created `.add`s elements.

Comment: @Patrioticcow, it can, but if you have a better way to find the container like an id-selector or class-selector, you should use them.

Comment: From the code in `getNot()` I understand that `$("#not_ul").on('click', '.add', function() {...});` is what you want.